# Solving $ F_{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (F_{i}\cdot F_{n-i}) $?

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers, convolution

I need to find $F_{n}$ in : 
$$ F_{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}  (F_{i}\cdot F_{n-i})  , F_0 = 0 , n>=2 $$

This equation screams convolution , I think , but I find it as a quite long solution sometimes.

Here, I first tried to play with the indexes :

$$ F_{n-1} = \sum_{i=1}^{n-2} (F_{i}\cdot F_{n-1-i}) $$

But this doesn't seem to do anything productive .

So convolution maybe :

Let $$ A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{∞} F_{i}\cdot x^n $$

Let $$ B(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{∞} F_{n-i}\cdot x^n $$

And $$C(x) = A(x)\cdot B(x) = \left(\sum_{n=0}^{∞} F_{i}\cdot x^n \right)\cdot \left(\sum_{n=0}^{∞} F_{n-i}\cdot x^n\right)$$

But I can't see how this helps me here , any hints and/or ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It's exactly the usual convolution if $F_0 = 0$.  Try looking at $A(x)^2$.

Comment: The only solution is $F_n=0$ for all $n$. Try calculating $F_1$, then $F_2$, then $F_3$, and see what happens.

Comment: $$(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n)^2=\sum_{n=2}^\infty(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_ka_{n-k})x^n$$

Comment: @Ethan Read my mind. +1

Comment: It appears OP has edited in that the recurrence holds only for $n\ge2$, so $F_1$ is arbitrary. So my earlier comment no longer applies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For convenience set $F_0=0$, and let

$$f(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}F_nx^n=\sum_{n\ge 1}F_nx^n\;.$$

Then

$$f(x)^2=\sum_{n\ge 2}\sum_{k=0}^nF_kF_{n-k}x^n=\sum_{n\ge 2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}F_kF_{n-k}x^n=\sum_{n\ge 2}F_nx^n=f(x)-F_1x\;,$$

and we have $f(x)^2-f(x)+F_1x=0$. Solve this as a quadratic in $f(x)$:

$$f(x)=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4F_1x}}2\;,$$

and since $f(0)=F_0=0$, we must choose

$$f(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4F_1x}}2\;.$$

The generating function for the Catalan numbers $C_n$ is

$$\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}=\sum_{n\ge 0}C_nx^n\;,$$

so

$$\begin{align*}
f(x)&=F_1x\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4F_1x}}{2F_1x}\right)\\\\
&=F_1x\sum_{n\ge 0}C_nF_1^nx^n\\\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{F_1^{n+1}}{n+1}\binom{2n}nx^{n+1}\\\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{F_1^n}n\binom{2n-2}{n-1}x^n\;,
\end{align*}$$

and $$F_n=\frac{F_1^n}n\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\;.$$

Comment: +1 But you spoiled the fun! =D Note the OP *has* set $F_0=0$.

Comment: @Peter: I did get carried away a bit: I got interested in the problem for its own sake! (The setting of $F_0$ to $0$ must have occurred while I was working on the problem.)

Comment: Of course I am kidding. It is a nice problem. In fact, the evaluation of the coefficients is not something that simple without knowledge of Catalan's GF. I guess I was simply pointing out my answer has been rendered useless =P

Comment: Would you care checking the proof of the second proposition [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441631/closure-of-a-connected-set-is-connected/441642#441642)?

Comment: @Peter: Everything looks okay to me.