# Components of a closed set are closed

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Prove that the components of a closed set $E$ are closed.

For each point $a$, let $C(a)$ be the component containing $a$. Then $C(a)$ is the union of all connected sets containing $a$. We must prove that $C(a)$ is closed.

We have $a\in C(a)\subseteq E$. Since $C(a)$ is connected, we have that its closure $\overline{C(a)}$ is also connected. Also, $\overline{C(a)}\subseteq\overline{E}=E$ since $E$ is closed. So we have $a\in C(a)\subseteq \overline{C(a)}\subseteq\overline{E}$. We must prove that $C(a)=\overline{C(a)}$. How?

Comment: Don't you mean that $C(a)$ is the *intersection* of all connected sets containing $a$?

Comment: @MJD Shouldn't it be the union? The set $\{a\}$ itself is connected...

Comment: $C(a)$ is the largest connected set containing $a$. Since $\bar{C(a)}$ is connected and contains $a$, you get the missing inclusion.

Comment: That's true, thanks minar!

Comment: More generally, components are always closed in the subspace topology. Then if $E$ is closed, they must be closed in the whole space.

Comment: @MJD I wonder if the converse is true: Given that the connected (or path-connected) components of a subspace are closed, it is itself closed in the ambient space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered by minar in the comments: since the [Closure of a connected set is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/441631/), $\overline{C(a)}$ is a connected set. By the definition of $C(a)$, $\overline{C(a)}\subseteq C(a)$, which means the equality holds.