# Are components of complement of a set $S$ always close to $S$

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness, separation-axioms, locally-connected

Suppose that $X$ is a connected topological space with a connected subset $S$, and let $K$ denote a component of $X\setminus S$. (All sets listed are assumed non-empty, apart from $\emptyset$ of course.)

**Question**. Is there an example of sets, as above, such that $\overline S\cap\overline K=\emptyset$?

*Remark*. If there is such an example, then there is one in which both $S$ and $K$ are closed. Indeed, given any example with $\overline S\cap\overline K=\emptyset$, we may replace $S$ with $\overline S$, and $K$ with $\overline K$, to produce an example with closed $S$ and $K$. Thus we could rephrase our question as follows.

**Question**. Is there a connected topological space $X$ with a connected and closed subset $S$, and a component $K$ of $X\setminus S$ such that $K$ is closed in $X$, and $S\cap K=\emptyset$ ?

*Remark*. No such example exists if $X$ is locally-connected. Indeed, in this case $K$ would be both closed in $X$ and (as a component) open, in the open and locally-connected $X\setminus S$, and hence also open in $X$, contradicting that $X$ is connected. (But perhaps the condition that $X$ is locally-connected is not essential. One may assume nice separation axioms.)

*Remark*. If there is such an example, then $K$ cannot be both  closed and open in $X$. Let $p$ be any boundary point of $K$. (Then $p$ belongs to $K$ since $p\not\in S$ and $K\cup\{p\}$ is connected.) Then any neighborhood $U$ of $p$ (and we may assume $U$ disjoint form $S$) would contain a point $q\in U\setminus K$ ( and $q\not\in S$). If $C$ is the component of $q$ in $X\setminus S$ then clearly $\overline C\cap K=\emptyset$ (though perhaps 
$\overline C\cap S\not=\emptyset$ for some such $C$). 
We have that $p\in\overline{\bigcup\{C: C \mathrm{\ is\ a\ component\ of\ } X\setminus S \mathrm{\ and\ } C\not= K\}}$ . In particular, $X\setminus S$ must have infinitely many components, if there is an example as in the above question.

I am sure the answer is known, and perhaps it is also easy, I do not know, but I can't think of one quickly. (The books *Topology* by John G. Hocking and Gail S. Young, and *Counterexamples in Topology* by Lynn Steen and J. Arthur Seebach, Jr., are two likely books to have a relevant example or a theorem.) 
The requirement that $X$ is connected is essential, and I need to think if the requirement, that $S$ is connected, is essential. If $S$ it is not connected, perhaps we could "make" it connected by adjoining its cone.

This question is motivated by the following one [Components and connectedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2315381) by [user @samiam](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/453588/samiam) , and 
by [my answer to it](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2316430) .

Thank you!

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen I only posted one question. It seems your example does indeed answer it, with $S=(0,1)$ and $K=(0,0)$. Why don't you post an answer here so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice metric example where $S$ and $K$ are both singletons (similar to example 119 in *Counterexamples in Topology*) is explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/93797/3457).

More drastic examples, where every component of $X \setminus S$ is separated
from $S$, can be found by looking for T1 spaces with a [dispersion point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_point), such as the one-point compactification of the rationals or the [Knaster-Kuratowski fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan). In such spaces choosing $S$ to contain only the dispersion point and $K$ any other singleton will do the trick.